# rc.local: Wait for script is finished

Tags: boot, bash, scripts, backup

I use an old netbook for backup purposes and sometimes for my work. I want to backup a remote server with rdiff-backup. The script should run at the end of the booting process, print a message on the screen ("Backup starts in 60 seconds, press Strg+C to cancel"), do the backup and power-off the computer. But I want to use the netbook not only for the backup, that is the reason for the message (Backup starts in 60 seconds).

So I modified `/etc/rc.local`. I start the computer and the backup starts and finishes correct. But unfortunately there is no message shown on the screen and therefore I don't have the possibility to stop the execution of the script. The computer just continues booting and logs in into the graphical environment.

What can I do so the computer waits until the script is finished (either with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or the normal end of the script)?

Comment: set a job in background in rc.local